# Align sherlock actionbar below listview

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an activity which is extended from SherlockActivity.

Situation:
The actionbar is not aligned above the listview, which uses the whole screen of the activity.
They are on top of each other!

I would like not to using paddingTop inside lisview... there have to be another cool way :).

Comment: Please share your layout file. Are you sure you are using the correct theme?

Comment: How embarrassing to ask such a question! I changed my theme in manifest to `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`. @Steelight if you change your comment to an answer, I will give you a reputation :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the correct theme? You should be using one of the Theme.Sherlock... ones.